# Why a subclass of a nested class cannot access the nesting class's private field here?

Tags: java, nested-class, private-members

Java code like this:

```
public class A {
        private static int a;

        public static class B {
                static void funcc() {
                        a = 3;
                }
        }
}


public class C extends A.B {
        public void func() {
                a = 1;
        }
}
```

When I try to compile it, an error occurs:

```
C.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
                a = 1;
                ^
  symbol:   variable a
  location: class C
1 error
```

Why this happens?

Comment: You have a lot of answers already, but you can learn more by compiling your code and then running the commands `javap A`, `javap A$B`, and `javap C`.  Also experiment by making `B` non-static and trying again.

Answer (score 3):

`B` is `static`. This makes it equivalent to declaring it at top level. It is not a nested class and does not have access to anything private in its lexically containing class.

Comment: I have changed my code, then, why `funcc()` in `class B` can access `a` directly, and `class A` can be compiled successfully?

Comment: Being `static` has nothing to do with it. Class `C` would not have access to `A.a` even if `B` were not static.

Comment: @UniMouS Because it's allowed to "peak" at A's variables; this is a power given to internal classes.  However, in this case this is just syntactic-sugar for `A.a`; the java compiler is smart enough to realize it, so it lets you do it.

Answer (score 2):

Nested class `B` has access to all of the fields and methods of it's enclosing because it is a member of `A`. Subclasses of `B` (that are not members of `A`) do not have that access.

Comment: I think I can understand this problem using your approach now. But think about this: subclass stands for a is-a relation, so `class C` is-a `class B`, and `class B` is a member of `class A`, so `class c` is a member of `class A`, what's wrong with my reasoning?

Comment: @UniMouS - You're mixing up lexical scoping with class hierarchy. These are different things. Class `C` is not a member of class `A` because it is not defined within `A`. There's an analogous issue with package scoping. Consider packages `a` and `b` with classes `a.A` and `b.B`. Now suppose that `b.B extends a.A`; this would not make `b.B` a member of package `a`. Class `b.B` will have no access to package-private members of `a.A` (or any other package-private items in package `a`).

Answer (score 0):

Internal classes don't extend their containing class; they are a class in their own right.

In your example, `B` is a class which has no methods and no fields.  It doesn't have a variable `a`.

However you could access the variable `a` inside of the `B` class, but this is only because `a` is in its closure; it can peak at `A`'s variables, which is the power of an internal class.